# Creating a command line application using Node

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm

I have a designed a Node application which is based on `yeoman` which I want it to distribute it to the user using npm.

The thing is after installing the application using node. I want to user to provide several  global commands through which he can have ease  using my application easily just like command are provided when using `grunt` or `bower` or `yeoman`.

```
$ bower install <package-name>
$ grunt serve
```

Similarly I want my application to provide some command so that user can have ease to handle it. let the command be `xyz`

```
$ xyz init #will initialize the application and create the scaffolding.
```

I already have the application designed on `node` I just want it to provide 
 the application installation using a global command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a bin script :

**package.json :**

```
  "bin": {
    "xyz": "index.js"
  }
```

**index.js :**

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

**Usage :**

```
npm install xyz
xyz foo bar
```

**Outputs :**

```
[ 'node', '/path/to/your/script/file', 'foo', 'bar']
```

For more information, you can refer to this blog post : 
[Building a simple command line tool with npm](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm)